# Spring Security get user's e-mail from id token for auditing

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, amazon-cognito

We have a Spring project which is both Spring Security OAuth2 Client and Resource Server. So it has all the integration part with our identity provider (AWS Cognito) and the authorization part is implemented by our team.

When logging in, Cognito response back three tokens: ID, access and refresh token. We store as cookies the two last tokens.

Then, we also are auditing creation data and last update date (for both use cases - author user and datetime).
For that, we are using a custom `AuditorAware`. The current version is something like this:

```
class PrincipalIdExtractor: AuditorAware<UUID> {
    override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<UUID> {
        val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
        return if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated)
            Optional.empty()
        else
            Optional.ofNullable(UUID.fromString(authentication.name))
    }
}
```

The thing is we would like to avoid a new request to database (we store the ID from identity provider and e-mail), or a new request to Cognito's userinfo endpoint.

`authentication.principal` is a Jwt, which does not bring the `email` claim attribute.

I cannot think about any viable solution right now. Is it possible to customize Cognito's access token and add custom claims to it? (Cognito's documentation is a bite messy)
Even storing the id token in the cookie means I will have to inject the data from the cookie and pass it throught the Spring's filters/interceptor.

What is the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to customize Cognito's access token and add custom claims to it?

I don't think so (couldn't find a way to do it). But ID tokens can be customized.

As a preambule, if you are not sure about the very different security requirements for OAuth2 clients and OAuth2 resource server, please take time to read the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) section in the introduction to my tutorials.

#### Client

I wouldn't store ID token, and ever more the refresh token, in cookies. The refresh token is something really secret that should not leave your servers.

Tokens are persisted in an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`. The default implementation is `AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, which uses a delegate: `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`. This means that by default, tokens (access, ID and refresh) are stored in session. This, off course, only applies to clients. Resource servers usually being stateless, do not store tokens.

If you are using K8s or any other distributed system, you might already be using [Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/index.html) or something to share session between client instances. If so, `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` in the security context of a request should be the same whatever the client instance and contain the ID token (it is built behind the scene using `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` and as so, session data)

It is then trivial to read the ID token from the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` in the security context and then add it in a custom header (let's say `X-ID-TOKEN`) before issuing a request to the resource server side of your app. You could even write a filter for that: add this custom header to each and every request send to resource servers you trust (and only those servers).

#### Resource Server

On the resource server side of your app, you can configure a custom `jwtAuthenticationConverter`. Such an authentication converter can return something else than `JwtAuthenticationToken`. This means you can define your own `AbstractAuthenticationToken` implementation containing the ID token claims (retrieved from the custom header using `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()`) in addition to access token ones.

I configure such a resource server in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_additional-header). This project is using one of my custom Spring Boot starters, but everything is open-source and in the same Github repo: if you clone it you can browse and debug the code to observe what happens.

#### Logging User OpenID Claims

Regarding your `AuditorAware`, it would fetch ID claims from a different place depending on where it is used:

- if logging login success & logout events or requests sent to the resource server(s), it would be on the client and the source could be the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` in the security context (it contains ID token already, no need to query the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`)
- if logging the requests on a resource server, then sending the ID token in a custom header and adding its claims to a custom `Authentication` instance would be my preferred way to go

Comment: Thanks for your anwser @ch4mp. Althought I have some questions:
1) where usually refresh tokens are stored? Our applications are deployed wiithin a Kubernetes cluster. Store them in memory doesn't sound good.
2) We have an implementation of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which I can use to extract the Id Token. So I send back the response to the client as a header, as you mentioned. I'm not sure how to pass it to the implementation of `AuditAware`. I'm going to update my question, adding where I have reached so far.

Comment: ok but client application angular... could change value of the X-ID-TOKEN and simulate another user

Comment: Angular apps can only be "public" OAuth2 clients, but as per Spring Security team recommandations, we should use only "confidential" clients => Angular should not be an OAuth2 client. The OAuth2 client should be a BFF between Angular and REST APIs. Apart from that, whatever the OAuth2 client is, why could you trust the access token it sends, but not the ID token? And even in that case, as you trust the access token, just check that the `sub` claim is the same in access and ID tokens, and you know that the ID token was issued for the same resource owner as the access token you trust.